# WPF combobox in a dialog window - can not select items falling beyond height of window

Tags: wpf, combobox, dialog

I have a dialog window in WPF with a `ComboBox`.  When the `ComboBox` items are more, they show beyond the height of the parent dialog window (in open state).

I am not able to select these items with the mouse (which are falling outside parent dialog window).

One possible solution is to increase height of the parent dialog window, but it doesn't look good.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `MaxDropDownHeight`of your `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="100" />
```